# I want to add css for safari and IE only in WordPress

Tags: php, css, safari

The plugin I used as a shortcode on my WordPress homepage is causing problems in Safari and Internet Explorer.

Since then, I have searched and applied css hacks dedicated to Safari and Internet Explorer, but it is not easy to apply because it is not a programmer.

How can I apply it?

I want to apply the following additional css:

```
.dgwt-wcas-search-wrapp {
        position: relative;
            right:100px;}
```

Comment: https://themeisle.com/blog/css-in-wordpress/